# Swift how to make for navigation middle section image and text next to each other

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have searched a lot on stackoverflow and I havent been able to find solution for my problem which is that I need to put in navigationBar in middle section image and text next to each other but apparently I was able only to place just image or just text

Here is my code

```
    let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    nav?.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    let image = UIImage(named: "icon_heart")
    imageView.image = image


    self.navigationItem.title = "App name"
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

I am aware that it on this way it accept only image which is titleView but I cant think of some normal solution and dont know is it even possible. Also if that is not possible how can I make then blank image and draw that icon image and text next to each other and append then that new image.

Edit:
Based on awph answer I have added code like this and it works fine for my case where I have always same characters in title

```
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    nav?.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: screenSize.width / 2 - 40, y: 15, width: 20, height: 20))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    let image = UIImage(named: "icon_heart")
    imageView.image = image
    nav!.addSubview(imageView)

    // label on top of the application that contain word
    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
    label.center = CGPointMake(screenSize.width / 2 - 15, 17)
    label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.text = "App Name"
    label.sizeToFit()
    nav!.addSubview(label)
```

Comment: Could you please create working JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You right, as said in documentation:

> // Custom view to use in lieu of a title. May be sized horizontally. Only used when item is topmost on the stack.

What you need to do is to create an `UIView`, add an `UImageView` (that contains your image) as subview (`view.addSubview(imageView)`) and then add a `UILabel` on it `view.addSubview(label)`.